# XML Data Loads in Chrome & Safari, but not Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xsd, xml-parsing

I've been racking my brain trying to figure this out since it hasn't been an issue with previous builds, but for the life of me cannot find an answer.

If you go to knitstitchmedia.com/sandbox/html/index.html in Chrome or Safari and input a zip code (just skip through the message pop-up box), you'll see the map loads with the store locations.  However, this isn't working in Firefox and simply reloads the page.

I'm not sure if it's because I'm not using English in the XML and that's causing Firefox not to work.  I do know that if there were an error in my XML entries, it wouldn't work in any browser; thus, I am completely confused on what the issue could be.

Thoughts?  And, THANK YOU!

Comment: As far as I can tell everything seems to work fine using Firefox 39. That being said the console gives the following error when I enter a zip code: `mismatched tag. Expected: </input>.` So I would suggest looking if you're properly closing all your tags.

Comment: Hmmm, so the map loads for you in Firefox?  I'm using FF 39 as well and when I enter a zip code, it just reloads the entire page.  Also, where would that error be for the closing tag </input>?  In the HTML itself?  Thank you!

Comment: I get: `mismatched tag. Expected: </input>.1 <unknown>:1:15` in the console the moment I open the map, but it loads just fine. Entering random numbers does drop me off all over the world though, so it might help if you could give me a valid zip code.

Comment: I see, well, I'm not sure how to fix that, but as long as the map loads it's fine.  However, I still don't see why it works for you and not me since we're using the same version of FF.

Comment: Actually, I just realized the problem.  Ugh, I'm so stupid sometimes!  I forgot this doesn't work very well on https, yet works perfectly fine on http.